# Weekday Shacharit at home without a minyan run time- Ashkenazi Nuasch

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer

Roughly how long does the average Shacharit at home without a minyan take, from the bracha over the talit gadol to the end? I am currently running 2 hours; while I am not the fastest Hebrew reader, it feels like that's too long. Using the Artscroll Interlinear Siddur, Nuasch Ashekenaz, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I suppose this question will be closed as opinion based, but still, I do it in an hour, and I am considered relatively slow in my experience (also it matters at what point do you put on talit gadol).

Comment: Are you saying all of Korbanot? Akeidah? Ma Tovu? Parshat Haman? Zekhirot? There are lots of things in the Siddur which many many many people don't say every day, but you wouldn't know it just from learning how to pray from a book.

Comment: Yes to all, @Double AA. I'm thinking of skipping the Akeidah, but many argue Korbanot is mandatory

Comment: I'm certainly not pressuring you to stop saying anything. I'm just pointing out that if you see a difference in time between you and others it could be because you are simply saying more things. If you feel overly burdened by your current time commitment, you should speak with your rabbi about what things should be dropped first. Generally speaking it's better to say fewer things (within reason) with proper Kavana than more things without.

Comment: One tip if it feels too long. Advice I heard is to set a limit based on what is reasonable for you and in line with your community, say an hour, and work with your Rav to define priorities of what you should say. Halacha has some very defined priorities (from the laws of one who comes late to a minyan). As you become more fluent and “accelerate” you can add in more content. 2 hours feels indeed very long for many.

Comment: I'd like to join @DoubleAA . Just to mention an example, the Yekke didn't say _Akeidah_ and _Ketoret_ on weekdays. Also I'd clarify in the question, whether you put the talit on right at the start or after R' Yishmael. But definitely CYLOR...

Comment: @JoshK "many argue Korbanot is mandatory" but not if it ruins the rest of your davening!

Comment: Is the question just "How long does it normally take?" In other words, would it be sufficient to provide a sourced answer that says, "The average amount of time someone takes to daven at home is X" or, "My friends and I typically can complete davening in Y"? Or are you looking for something more than that? If the latter, could you please clarify what you want to know?

Answer (score -3):

How quickly do you count money?
The davening should be said at the speed which one counts money.

Comment: R Chaim Soloveitchik of Brisk [allegedly] said he counted money quite quickly so he prayed quickly too.

Comment: I definitely daven *with kavanna* much slower than I count money, @RibbisRabbiAndMore, is there a source for that guideline, basic though it may be?

Comment: @double AA is that written down anywhere, out of curiosity?

Comment: I don't really understand that answer. How much money corresponds to a full shacharis davening? It would take longer to count a lot of money than to count less money. It takes longer to say a lot of words than to say fewer words.

Comment: @Daniel I think the idea is a speed of one word per the time it takes to count one coin. So the total amounts should not matter

Comment: @JoelK Are you counting how many coins adding up the values of the coins? Are you taking time to pile them into groups, or making an unordered pile? Are you writing down sums or are you keeping it in your head? Are all the coins the same or do you have to spend time checking what each is worth? Basically, this is not a very helpful measurement of time.